# DbCommand , Must Declare a variable error

Tags: ado.net, dbcommand

This is my code. I have added the db parameter too but it still shows me error (on execution). Must declare a scalar variable

```
       DbCommand command;
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(
                                                        @"SELECT         isnull(UpsellService_OID,'') UpsellService_OID," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(ServiceName,'') ServiceName," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(ServiceDescription,'') ServiceDescription," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(Create_By,'') Create_By," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(Create_Date,'') Create_Date," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(Modify_By,'') Modify_By," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(Modify_Date,'') Modify_Date," + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "       isnull(Active_f,'') Active_f" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "FROM   TRGPAYROLL.ZONG.UPSELLSERVICES   " + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "WHERE  1 = 1");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idObject.ServiceName))
        {
            query.Append(" AND ServiceName like '%'  @ServiceName  '%'");
        }

        command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query.ToString());
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idObject.ServiceName))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "ServiceName", DbType.String, idObject.ServiceName);
        }

        return command;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the last part of your code in this way

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idObject.ServiceName))
    {
        query.Append(" AND ServiceName like @ServiceName");
    }

    command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query.ToString());
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idObject.ServiceName))
    {
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@ServiceName", DbType.String, "%" + idObject.ServiceName + "%");
    }
```

The wildcard are added directly to the value of the parameter, while the placeholder of the parameter should be free from any string concatenations. However there are many details missing to be sure of the correctness of this answer. In particular Ican only assume the inner workings of the methods `GetSqlStringCommand` and `AddInParameter`

Answer (score 0):

`@ServiceName` variable is not declared in your SQL statement. Append to beggining of it something like

```
DECLARE @ServiceName AS nchar(32)
SET @ServiceName = ....
```